# Fetching Firestore document when offline fails and doesn't fallback to local storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm using FireStore in Expo React Native.

My code:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import '@firebase/firestore';

store = {
    uid: null,
    data: null
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export async function startUpAsync() {
    await firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
    try {
        await new Promise((resolve => {
            try {
                firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                    store.uid = user?.uid;
                    resolve();
                })
            }
            catch (e) {
                logError(e);
                return null;
            }
        }));
        const doc = await firebase.firestore().collection('my-collection').doc(store.uid).get();
        if (doc.exists) {
            store.data = doc.data();
        }
        else {
            store.data = {...initalData};
        }
        return store.data;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test my code with no internet connection.

I first run my app with connection, authenticating and fetching documents fine. Then I added the following line to `startUpAsync` after `setPersistence`:

```
firebase.firestore().disableNetwork()
```

Authentication works fine, however fetching the document fails. I expected to get document from local storage. Message:

```
Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

Am I missing something in my Firebase configuration?

Versions:

```
"@firebase/firestore": "1.12.1"
"expo": "37.0.0"
"firebase": "7.9.0"
"react": "16.9.0"
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.0.tar.gz"
```

I'm guessing this could also be a problem with my simulator somewhat, didn't test this on a physical device yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the configuration call

```
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
```